# Newbie (spark dataframes) - df.count().show() returns AttributeError

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

Apologize for the newbie question. Am just learning.

I am simply trying to create a spark dataframe from a Cloudant db and count the number of entries. After calling the function to count, I am getting an error:

```
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-56a7e10a510b> in <module>()
----> 1 count(cloudantdata,spark)

<ipython-input-2-f2dcd9d73d7e> in count(df, spark)
      1 def count(df,spark):
      2     #TODO Please enter your code here
----> 3     df.count().show()
      4     return

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'show'
```

**See Notebook:**
https://apsportal.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/c83c959b-2994-4ac7-9af7-f9d33d4dc461/view?access_token=6a057cadfdd07252e5977a5eb65936185673dd1d1213ab8a003874edbfde6808

Comment: hmm - I think I had the wrong URL. This should have worked instead: https://apsportal.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/c83c959b-2994-4ac7-9af7-f9d33d4dc461/view?access_token=6a057cadfdd07252e5977a5eb65936185673dd1d1213ab8a003874edbfde6808

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`count()` is an *action* (as opposed to a *transformation*), so it returns a non-DataFrame object -- in this case an `int` representing the number of rows in the DataFrame.  An `int` has no method called `show()` on it.

Just simply `return df.count()`.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks, didn't look closely enough... Edited.

Comment: Oh, silly me. Thank you for entertaining such a newbie question. I get it now.